Looking for a Challenging Problem Book for High School Calculus 1
I'm searching for a book with challenging problems specifically for Calculus 1, aimed at high school students. My teacher asked me to find resources that cover topics like limits, differentiation (including implicit and higher-order derivatives and related rates), and integration techniques (such as substitution and parts, as well as volume of solids of revolution and trig integration but without the inverse trig functions).
The problem I’ve run into is that most calculus textbooks, even famous ones like Thomas’ Calculus, tend to used in all of high school books, even in their challenging sections. I’ve found plenty of problem books for real analysis, but these are too advanced for high school students. I've also come across problem books for calculus, but they tend to be fairly easy and don’t offer the level of difficulty I'm looking for.
Does anyone know of a dedicated problem book for Calculus 1 that contains genuinely challenging exercises? It doesn’t have to be exclusively a problem book—any book with difficult calculus problems would be helpful.

This is a nice book, but maybe a little advanced for a high school student

@SineoftheTime does it have challenging problems?

It depends on your definition of "challenging"

You can read a sample on Amazon, it's the preface basically

Schaum's Outlines.

See the answers (and comments to them) to Calculus book with extremely hard questions AND Challenging problems in calculus and the suggestions in this Mathematics Educators SE answer.

It almost sounds like you want MIT Integration Bee or Putnam type questions.

This question is similar to: Challenging problems in calculus. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
